# Inserting an integer at the end of the list and deleting at nth position

Tags: c++, linked-list

So, in my linked list program, what I want it to do is to ask the user how many numbers to input, and enter the numbers, and add those numbers at the end of the list. Then, it will print the list. After that, the user will choose a position of element in the list to delete and the list will be printed again.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Node{

int data;
  Node* link;
};

Node* head;

void Insert(int data){ //insert an integer at the end of the list

  Node* temp = new Node();
  Node* temp2 = new Node();

  temp->data = data;
  temp->link = NULL;
  if(head = NULL){
    head = temp;
    return;
  }
  temp2 = head;
  while(temp2->link != NULL){
    temp2 = temp2->link;
  }

  temp2->link = temp;

}

void Delete(int n){ //delete an integer at nth position

  Node* temp1 = new Node();
  temp1 = head;
  if(n == 1){ //if the first node is to be deleted
    head = temp1->link; //now head points to second node
    delete temp1; //delete first node
    return;
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < n-2; i++){
    temp1 = temp1->link; //temp1 points to (n-1)th node
  }
  Node* temp2 = temp1->link; //temp2 points to nth node
  temp1->link = temp2->link; // pointing to (n+1)th node
  delete temp2; //deleting nth node

}

void Print(){ //print out the list
  Node* printNode = head;
  cout << "List: ";

  while(printNode != NULL){
    cout << printNode->data;
    cout << " ";
    printNode = printNode->link;
  }

  cout << "\n";
}

int main(){

  int x, count, n;

  head = NULL; //start with an empty list

  cout << "How many numbers? " << endl;
  cin >> count;

  for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){

    cout << "Enter number: ";
    cin >> x;
    Insert(x);
  }

  Print();

  cout << "Enter position to delete: ";
  cin >> n;

  Delete(n);
  Print();

  return 0;

}
```

After accepting the first number, the program stops working. Can I know where I did the code wrong and what can I do to make this code more efficient? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Only skimmed the code currently. `if(head = NULL)` should be `if(head == NULL)`. Don't know if that solves the entire problem but it is a start

Comment: @tomasbasham that's a big facepalm on my part. It's fixed now. Thanks man.

Comment: No problem. May I point out that it will be more efficient to save a reference to the tail of the linked list instead of having to traverse through it every time you insert a number

Comment: @tomasbasham Another great tip, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to rethink your insertion function. The part that your code crashes on is during the while loop insertion. If you want `temp2` to hold data then you need to dynamically allocate space for it which you did. However, you are just using it as a position indicator (to traverse the list) - so why do you need to allocate space just to point to head or any other nodes location in your list?

Here's how I would insert into the list (at the back of course):

```
void Insert(int data){ //insert an integer at the end of the list

    Node* temp = new Node();

    // This is to ensure that temp was created -> Also called defensive programming.
    if (!temp)
   {
        cout << "We did not have enough space alloted to dynamically allocate a node!" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    temp->data = data; // Bad nominclature for program; Don't use the same name twice.
    temp->link = NULL;

    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        // This is to help traverse the linked list without having to
        // manipulate the position of what head points to.
        Node *Pos_Indicator = head;

        while (Pos_Indicator->link != NULL)
        {
            Pos_Indicator = Pos_Indicator->link;
        }

        // We are at the end of the list, it is now safe to add.
        Pos_Indicator->link = temp;

        // Should probably have a check here for whether it was successful or not.
    }

}
```

I was able to compile and run your code to completion with no other problems. Let me know if this helps!

EDIT: or you know `(head = NULL)` to `(head == NULL)` works too :(

Comment: This is a great help and teaches a lot. And for my bad nominclature, which part should I change?

Comment: After using Pos_Indicator, is says that Pos_Indicator is not declared in the function. Followed yours to the letter so I'm not sure what's wrong.

Comment: How did you declare it? I was able to compile and run in VS 2013 with no problems.

Comment: it's declared using Node* Pos_Indicator right? Or is there a header I'm missing? I'm using dev cpp, I'll try running it using VS.

Comment: @nisyedlah - that's correct, I'm not familiar with dev cpp - I've just run it using the g++ compiler on a virtual linux machine and it worked as well there.

Answer (score 2):

Big facepalm on my part, only a small mistake. Code has been corrected.

```
if(head == NULL){
    head = temp;
    return;
}
```